# How can I make sparql queries to the active repository from a graphdb plugin in java/kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, sparql, graphdb, rdf4j

I'm developing a graphdb plugin using graphdb's Plugin API.

I need my plugin to retrieve some statements from the current active graphdb repository to process them further.
I want to make a query with this format:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix proof: <http://www.ontotext.com/proof/>
select ?rule ?s ?p ?o ?context where {
    values (?subject ?predicate ?object) {(<urn:Mary> <urn:hasChild> <urn:John>)}
    ?ctx proof:explain (?subject ?predicate ?object) .
    ?ctx proof:rule ?rule .
    ?ctx proof:subject ?s .
    ?ctx proof:predicate ?p .
    ?ctx proof:object ?o .
    ?ctx proof:context ?context .
}
```

If it's relevant, the stated query should be handled by another plugin: [the proof plugin](https://github.com/Ontotext-AD/graphdb-proof-plugin).
This should happen automatically if the query is formulated correctly and the plugin is active and running on the repository.

RDF4J offers some classes to formulate and send queries to a `RepositoryConnection` object.

```
Repository db = new SailRepository(new MemoryStore());

// Open a connection to the database
try (RepositoryConnection conn = db.getConnection()) {
  String filename = "example-data-artists.ttl";
  try (InputStream input = Example15SimpleSPARQLQuery.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + filename)) {
    // add the RDF data from the inputstream directly to our database
    conn.add(input, "", RDFFormat.TURTLE);
  }

  // We do a simple SPARQL SELECT-query that retrieves all resources of type `ex:Artist`,
  // and their first names.
  String queryString = "PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/> \n";
  queryString += "PREFIX foaf: <" + FOAF.NAMESPACE + "> \n";
  queryString += "SELECT ?s ?n \n";
  queryString += "WHERE { \n";
  queryString += "    ?s a ex:Artist; \n";
  queryString += "       foaf:firstName ?n .";
  queryString += "}";

  TupleQuery query = conn.prepareTupleQuery(queryString);

  // A QueryResult is also an AutoCloseable resource, so make sure it gets closed when done.
  try (TupleQueryResult result = query.evaluate()) {
    // we just iterate over all solutions in the result...
    for (BindingSet solution : result) {
      // ... and print out the value of the variable binding for ?s and ?n
      System.out.println("?s = " + solution.getValue("s"));
      System.out.println("?n = " + solution.getValue("n"));
    }
  }
} finally {
  // Before our program exits, make sure the database is properly shut down.
  db.shutDown();
}
```

The first issue is that I haven't found a way to get an object of the correct type pointing to the current working repository for graphdb.
The plugin API works with a `PluginConnection` object ([documented here](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/plug-in-api.html#repository-internals)) offering some utilities, but which does not seem to allow this kind of interfacing.
I was able to list all repositories present at localhost:7200, but I don't know how to distinguish the current working repository; if I want access to a repository I must know its id/name which is user-defined.

[The docs show a possible solution using configuration files](https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/using-graphdb-with-the-rdf4j-api.html).
I don't think I can rely on those. I can't be sure of where they are placed in a graphdb installation and it seems impractical in the context of a plugin.
Also, they don't seem to show which repository is currently being queried.

I have considered using the `getStatements()` function offered by `PluginConnection`. This allows for some basic filtering based on subject, predicate and object.
I find this insufficient for 2 reasons:

1. I don't know how to use it to reproduce the behavior of more complex queries like the one above
2. I can't use rdf lists in the object like this `?ctx proof:explain (?subject ?predicate ?object) .`